# Why does the argument asyncCb in async.Map show an undefined function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, async.js

I am working through an Electron book and I have problems understanding this code:

```
function inspectAndDescribeFiles(folderPath, files, cb) {
  async.map(files, (file, asyncCb) => {
   console.log(asyncCb)  //
   let resolvedFilePath = path.resolve(folderPath, file);
   inspectAndDescribeFile(resolvedFilePath, asyncCb);
  }, cb);
}
```

The output in the console is:

```
function (err, v) {
  results[index] = v;
  callback(err);
}
```

My problem is understanding where this function comes from. It is not defined anywhere in the code, so I am wondering if this is something to do with the async.map module?

[Source code for those interested](https://github.com/paulbjensen/cross-platform-desktop-applications/blob/master/chapter-02/lorikeet-electron/app.js)

Comment: There is a typo in console.log(asyncCB instead of asyncCb). Was this a post typo?

Comment: Yes, a post typo. Sorry.

Comment: *"I am wondering if this is something to do with the async.map module?"* Yes: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/93515e3b0df21c0910658788d1aa6c2ef21e1775/lib/internal/map.js#L13-L16